# Upload/Display video on my web page using PHP:

Tags: php, html, mysql

Am trying to save and display video on my page. Videos are saved to my     directory and name,url are saved my db.
Am going to display my video on watch.php page. But the problem is     videos didn't played. what i made wrong. Help me

```
**index.php:**
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db("websites", $conn);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
    $url="http://127.0.0.1/PHP/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploaded    /$name";
    mysql_query("insert into video value('$name','$url') ");
}
```

?>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Video Upload and Playback</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box">
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select Video: <br/>
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />      
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "<br />".$name."has been uploaded";
}  

?>    
</div>
<div id="box">
<h3>List of videos</h3>
<?php

$query=mysql_query("select * from video");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$name=$row['name'];
$url=$row['url'];
echo "<a href='watch.php?name=$name'>$url</a> <br />";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my video display page
    **watch.php:**

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db("websites", $conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Watch videos</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $query=mysql_query("select * from video where name='$name'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $name=$row['name'];
    $url=$row['url'];
    }
    echo "You are watching ".$name."<br />";
    echo "<embed src='$url' width='560' height='315'></embed>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error !";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css file.
    **style.css:**
    body {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

```
#box{
background: #333;
padding: 10px;
width: 50%;
margin: 50px auto;
}

input{
background: #444;
color: #fff;
border: 0px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px 0px;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

#url{
background: #444;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You can also try `<video>` tags of HTML5

Answer (score 1):

remove the spaces after folder name "Uploaded"

```
move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
$url="http://127.0.0.1/PHP/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploaded/$name";
```

Comment: Thanks Arun.. But still its same issue.. ahh Thats Stack overflow space issue.. am used without space $url="http://127.0.0.1/PHP/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploaded/$name";

Comment: //try this// $url="http://127.0.0.1/PHP/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploaded/".$name;

Answer (score 0):

In watch.php, your embed code is outside of the loop:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$url=$row['url'];
}
echo "You are watching ".$name."<br />";
echo "<embed src='$url' width='560' height='315'></embed>";
```

try to change it to this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$url=$row['url'];   
echo "You are watching ".$name."<br />";
echo "<embed src='$url' width='560' height='315'></embed>";
```

}

PS.formatting doesn't seem to work, but you get my point, just move the curly brace to below these "echos".

So now embed code is inside the loop, and it will know what $name is.

If none of this works, please post which error or result you get and we'll fix it further. Btw.this code could be much much simpler.

Comment: Yes i got it, I changed. I didn't get any error on my page. Still the videos didn't  play.

Comment: can you put var_dump($row); inside that while loop and tell me what it outputs?